# reader.onload = function(e) not executing javascript

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm trying to upload a file to a sharepoint list item. The problem is, whenever I call the reader.onload = function(e), I get an exception. Here is my code:

```
var element = document.getElementById("dev");  
        var file = element.files[0]; 
var parts = element.value.split("\\");  
        var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];   
readFile(file,element,fileName  );
```

readFile function:

```
function readFile(file,element,fileName ){


        //Read File contents using file reader  
        var reader = new FileReader();  
        reader.onload = function(e) {  
            uploadFile(e.target.result, fileName);  
        }  
        reader.onerror = function(e)   
        {  
            alert(e.target.error);  
        }  
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); 


 }
```

Comment: Where is function uploadFile and what exception do you get?

Comment: To better help you, include your HTML and all relevant code - otherwise we dont know where to look or how its _supposed_ to work. But at first glance, the event is actually `loadend`, so try `reader.addEventListener( 'loadend', handler )` Also, a reader takes a `File` object as an argument, not a path (use `fetch` for that, and you cant modify these paths as they point to local tmp folders).